# Illegal use of filter typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm searching through array of objects. If the `item` is having status code `1` I'm pushing to `openIssue` and if it is `3`, it's pushing to `inProgressIssue`.

Below is my code:

```
openIssue = [];
inProgressIssue = [];
issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter((item) => {
  if (item.statusId === '1') {
    openIssue.push(item);
  } else if (item.statusId === '3') {
    inProgressIssue.push(item);
  }
});
```

I got a code review comments:

> Illegal use of filter

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You do not need a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), instead you need a [`foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: a filter expect a returned value.
with .forEach method, you iterate over the array and can do whatever you want with each value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that error because filter expect you to return bool, filter always do that. Yes filter is an iteration but the return values should be boolean, that is how it is made for,
I advice you to use the filter like this which is very easy. you can use [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) too, which doesn't expected to return anything.

```
openIssue = issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter(a => a.statusId === '1');
inProgressIssue = issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter(a => a.statusId === '3');
```

here [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will return the `statusid` and retur the values fitlered

```js
let issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint = [{
  statusId: '1',
  name: 'asfadsf'
}, {
  statusId: '2',
  name: 'asfadsf11'
}, {
  statusId: '3',
  name: 'asfadsf6636'
}];
let openIssue = [];
let inProgressIssue = []
openIssue = issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter(a => a.statusId === '1');
inProgressIssue = issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter(a => a.statusId === '3');

console.log('open', openIssue, 'inprogress', inProgressIssue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because filter method expects you to return a boolean value. You should use forEach method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` as below:

```
inProgressIssue = [];

issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.forEach(item => {
  if (item.statusId === '1') {
    openIssue.push(item);
  } else if (item.statusId === '3') {
    inProgressIssue.push(item);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter needs to return a boolean since it is asking for a condition to filter by. Also it creates a new Array.

You could simply rewrite like this to use filter:

```
openIssue = issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter(item => item.statusId === '1');

inProgressIssue = issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter(item => item.statusId === '3');
```